# Can't access array for unserialize

Tags: php, postgresql, serialization

I'm storing my json filter as serialized data in my postgre database, the insert works very well.

Now, i need to query select, and unserialize my filters.

Postgresql query gives me this array of array ($results) :

```
  array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id_filtres_stock' => int 7
      'id_liseo_utilisateurs' => int 46
      'filtres' => string 'O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"ville";s:9:"ABBEVILLE";}' (length=47)
      'nom_filtre' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id_filtres_stock' => int 8
      'id_liseo_utilisateurs' => int 46
      'filtres' => string 'O:8:"stdClass":0:{}' (length=19)
      'nom_filtre' => string 'test' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id_filtres_stock' => int 9
      'id_liseo_utilisateurs' => int 46
      'filtres' => string 'O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:7:"nom_pdg";s:16:"AUCHAN BAGNOLET ";}' (length=57)
      'nom_filtre' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

I need to convert 'filtres'  back with unserialize(), so i'm trying to access the filtres variable  :

```
echo($results[0][0]->filtres) ;
```

It doesn't work and display the whole array.

I've even tryed this :

```
$d = (string)$results[0][0]->filtres;

$d = unserialize($d);
```

with no luck .

Any idea ?

> EDIT : Ok, I 'm accessing it well now :

```
 $d = $result[0]['filtres'];
 $f = unserialize($d);
```

Thank you , resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get it like this:

```
$filtres = results[0]['filtres'];
```

Then you can unserialize it:

```
$filtres = unserialize($filtres);
```

Comment: Ok, I access it well now, but now i've got this error when trying to unserialize: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: That means you are trying to echo an object. var dump it, and you will see which properties there are. You can access properties like this `echo $filtres->someVar`. I think `nom_pdg` is the property name, and `AUCHAN BAGNOLET ` is the value (`echo $filtres->nom_pdg;`)?

Comment: thanks! can you mark this as the correct answer please? oh that was fast lol